# Oracle call_form statement not working

Tags: oracle, call, oracleforms

I've a problem with Oracle forms 11g R2. I'm upgrading from Oracle forms 10 but I think that problem is not because of the upgrade.

I've installed Oracle Fusion Middleware and Oracle forms 11g R2. I've setup webutil. Installation is correct because I can get a test form.

I 've upgraded old forms version 10 and recompiled them to the forms 11g R2.

I'm getting login form for my app. But when I log in I'm not redirected to the second form.

I've added a messages to track where is a problem and I'm logging OK. I can see a session on database.

I've added two messages before and after call_form statement.

```
    message('Calling a new form...');
    call_form(select_new_form_proc(6),hide,do_replace);
    message('New form called...');
```

I'm getting first popup window and text "Calling a new form..." on the bottom line of the login form.

After I click OK, I don't get a second popup window. Just a message "**New form called...**" on the bottom line of the login form.

So statement `call_form(...)` is ignored.

Most of the setup options in `formsweb.cfg` are defaults.

Any ides what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Did that code work in Forms 10g? Because, generally speaking, CALL_FORM expects form name, enclosed in single quotes. What does `select_new_form_proc(6)` represent? Especially "(6)"? If it is a parameter value you'd like to pass to a called form, that's invalid - you should use PARAMLIST parameter. Open Forms Online Help system and search for CALL_FORM; you'll see an example which might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `select_new_form_proc` is a function returning a form name from your look-up table of form id `6`, you may be missing the extension of the form name, So, you may prefer using below :

```
call_form(select_new_form_proc(6)||'.fmx',hide,do_replace);
```

there should be no problem other than that.

Comment: I can't test it now, but - I don't remember I ever used form extension, so I wouldn't say that it makes a difference. But hey, never say never.

Comment: @Littlefoot you're right friend, i can't see any other type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Ozhan. Your answer put me to to the right direction. I've added "select_new_form_proc(6)" in the message so I can check your idea about fmx extension and  find out an issue. Looks like paths of the forms are with full path in db. On old 10g forms server I have E:.....fmx. On new 11g forms server I've changed drive letter to D:. I'll change this tomorrow and check it than.

Best regards...

Comment: thank you too, nice to hear these, but you could write this as comment by pressing "add a comment" beneath my answer. Have a nice day.